# Slight FTIR band intensity changes across several different copper salt spectra: relevant for characterization?

Tags: ir-spectroscopy

I have several spectra of different samples which are probably all copper (neutral and/or basic) acetate(s) and which are very similar. I present them overlayed and (some of them) stacked:

[image: Overlayed spectra]

[image: Stacked spectra]

My question is: can I assume all the samples are qualitatively identical or do subtle/slight intensity differences in the same bands mean a qualitative difference?

These are all spectra made with a pellet of KBr and I intend a qualitative characterisation to compare with literature, not a quantitative one.

Comment: Chemists prefer IR spectra with (remnant) %transmittance along the ordinate axis, and with one (or even two) brakes in the abscissa at about 2200 1/cm (or even a twice at about 1000 1/cm) instead of a straight linear axis; it renders the spectrum more legible.  In most cases, the software of the spectrometer offers this and it is only a few clicks away.  Is it a transmittance spectrum with a pellet of KBr, or a neat film/ATR?  Do you intend a qualitative characterisation to compare with literature, or a quantitative one? Do the traces represent several batches of one (what?) intended product?

Answer (score 1):

(Answered after your edit of your question:)

*Some* variation in the location of the absorption bands (*vs.* 1/cm) and their intensities (*vs.* remnant transmittance) is unavoidable due to the interaction of your analyte (here: your copper salt/salts) with the matrix (here: pellet of KBr) compared to recording a neat film of your sample.  The spectra depicted by the trace in magenta and blue seem to be a little bit different from the others, *perhaps* due to some humidity (KCl exposed to air, or a sample not completely dried, or both, ...).  On first view of the current representation, the other look very similar, compared with each other.

- As your data represent infrared spectroscopy, figure out how to change the representation such that your ordinate is in remnant %transmittance instead of absorption.  Let the spectrometer's software do this for you.  For a visual inspection of the data, a split in the abscissa, too, for example around 2000 1/cm eases the visual inspection *a lot* -- equally something typically offered by the software of the spectrometer. (On good instruments, both changes do not alter the raw data collected by the spectrometer.) For example:

[image]

([source](https://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/virttxtjml/Spectrpy/InfraRed/infrared.htm), the picture was edited by addition of horizontal lines)

- Determine the barycentre of your absorption bands. Likely, as you start with IR spectroscopy, a deviation of *about* 1/cm is not an issue  (ask your instructor).  In other words, if the peak pic by the software *suggests* 1837.54 1/cm, a report like 1838 1/cm likely is good enough (ask your instructor).
- For each *important* absorption band, have a look about the shape, note if it is a particular broad absorption band -- in your example, around 3350 1/cm, for example.
- Beside location, an other important information provided by IR spectroscopy is the *intensity* of the absorption band.  In the representation of %T, imagine three equal parts between the baseline on top, and the most intense absorption band on the bottom.  A bit like the three horizontal blue dotted lines added to the picture above. The absorbtion bands in the first strip are then (semiquantitatively) classified as of *weak*, the ones reaching till the second strip of *medium*, and the ones reaching down to the third strip of *strong* intensity.  (As an example, the edited spectrum above contains an absorption band of medium intensity at about 3500 1/cm, and two strong ones at about 1700 and 1500 1/cm.)
- *Compare* localisation and absorption band intensity of the spectral data recorded by you, with data found in a reference (textbook, journal article, data base).  Are all *important* absorption bands found in your spectrum mentioned in the literature reference?  Do you find all *important* absorption bands described in the literature reference in your spectrum, too?  Are there some *important* bands in addition or missing?
- Of course you may compare sample #1 with sample #2, with sample #3, etc.,
  too.

Only by growing experience you will learn what *important* absorption bands in infrared spectroscopy are.  Because -- in contrast to other spectroscopic techniques -- it is rather the exception than the general case that you may correlate each absorption band with a structural element in the structure of your compound.

For future reference I suggest to record the IR data either already in the %T mode, or (second best) to convert them into this form.  This allows you to check rapidly if even the most intense absorption band does not hit a transmittance of 0% (such an occurence were a rapid indication of a sample with to high concentration of X in your pellet of KBr.)